# Is Apple Music (the app, not the service) for Windows scriptable?

Tags: itunes, windows, script

Apple [used to support COM](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238560/62735) as API for iTunes. AFAIK, this support has been officially dropped. Now with [Apple Music for Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459390/62735) on the horizon, is there any information available whether, and if so how, it will be scriptable? Will there be a [COM automation interface](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) again or some other means of programmatic access to the library data like the [iTunes Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ituneslibrary) on macOS?

Comment: I'm going to push this to SU since they will have far more expertise on windows scripting technologies than us. I see this as on topic at Ask Different, but Apple Music is only peripherally core to this - at its core it's about the OS you choose and how to script on that OS. Please flag if you feel this action is harmful and you really want it open on Ask Different as opposed to Super User.

Comment: We can't answer questions about something that has not been released.

Comment: [MusicKit](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/) is a thing.

Comment: Is there a Windows version for MusicKit?

Comment: @DavidPostill The preview is already in the Windows App Store. It has been released.

Comment: The app is out of preview. The final version has recently been released. The questions still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Apple Music for Windows is not scriptable. There is no public API.

To the following questions:

> Is there some API for Apple Music for Windows?
> Will there be some API?
> And if so, where can I find the documentation?

Apple code level support gave me this answer:

> We have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.

> If you would like for Apple to consider adding support for such features, please submit your suggestion request via Feedback Assistant (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). For more information on Feedback Assistant, please visit https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting.